# Find the remote userid causing updates on my table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, windows

Small question here. I found some answer close to it but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Here is the situation: I have a SQL Server trigger on a table. Its task is to record the username (logon id) of the user who make some insert/update/delete.

So far, it's not so hard to find the information.

The complicated part is coming. The insert statements are made through an Access view with a generic SQL Server account.

What I want to do is find the (Windows) user that launch Access. I was able to find the host name (the name of the computer) but how can I found the user?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to use Windows Authentication instead of a SQL Server login? I'm unaware if Access supports those connections but I'd imagine so.

Comment: One detail was not relevant for my question so I didn't mention it: the SQL Server database is located in another domain (windows domain) than the users running Access. That's why SQL Server authentication is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, if you are using a generic username to log in to SQL Server. Host name is as close as you can get. It shouldn't be hard to translate it to a user name with a query in Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree, this is not really complicated but not 100% reliable :(